# Cannot access files inside asar archive in electron app

Tags: electron

Electron version: 1.2
Operating system: Windows

Cannot able to access the files inside asar archive using readFileSync:

```html
var fs = require('fs');
var SQL = require('sql.js');
var filebuffer = fs.readFileSync('asar:'+ __dirname + './app/data/sample.db');

I've also tried using 
trial 1 : readFileSync('D:/Sample-App/app.asar/app/data/sample.db');

trial 2 : readFileSync('./app/data/sample.db');

trial 3 : process.noAsar= true;
readFileSync('./app/data/sample.db');
```

None of the trials worked out. If I try without using app.asar, I was able to access the db file. So Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that once you package your app to an asar, your file paths don't work.

> ```
> fs.readFileSync('asar:'+ __dirname + './app/data/sample.db')
> ```

This is close. You don't need "asar:" and you should use the path module to make your life easier.

Try constructing a path dynamically using `path`. Also your main entry point JS is probably already running in the app folder. Try something like this:

```
path.join(__dirname, '/data/sample.db');
```

This will create a valid, absolute path for each operating system (paths in Windows use \ whereas OSX and Linux uses /). Remember `__dirname` is whatever your current directory is, so everything after that has to be relative to it.

Comment: @srivignes remember to accept one of these answers if it helped :)

Comment: @srivignes to accept an answer on stackoverflow, you have to click the gray checkmark icon to the left of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should provide a protocol prefix to the path. For example: "file://[your path here]".