# Electron: Crash after build exe

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, wiki.js

I am tring merge [wiki.js](https://github.com/Requarks/wiki) with [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/)
and, I can make simple electron application as below code

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path')

var winGlobal;

// This will run express server with port 3000 within 3~6 seconds
require('./server/index.js')

// load the url after 9 seconds.
setTimeout(() => winGlobal.loadURL('http://localhost:3000'), 9000);

function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1200,
        height: 900,
        webPreferences: {
            //   preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })
    winGlobal = win;
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()

    app.on('activate', () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow()
        }
    })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
    ...
    "main": "main.js"
    ...
    "build": {
        "productName": "wiki.js-electron",
        "appId": "com.electron.wiki",
        "directories": {
          "output": "build"
        },
        "asar": true
    },

    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "express": "4.17.1",
        "sqlite3": "5.0.0",
        ...
    }
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "electron": "^12.0.2",
        "electron-builder": "^22.10.5",
        ...
    }
}
```

And, I can run the current project with `npx electron .`
[image: Screen]

To build exe, I can build with `npx electron-build`, and new exe file is generated without error log.
[image: Screen2]

but, the exe is crash without any error.

How I can fix this?

---

Full Source code Github: https://github.com/nkhs/wiki.js-electron
Built exe: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/535a59714d4d957f478c14816ee0142e20210330143018/0d5cbe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found Solution
Instead of running with a mouse double click at File Explorer, I used windows command prompt to run exe, and, from there, I can find error logs.

So, I found: the some relative path is not working, because, the electron pack source code with asar.

and, some file operate is not working, etc `fs.read`, `fs.readDir`.

[Cannot access files inside asar archive in electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559596/cannot-access-files-inside-asar-archive-in-electron-app) ,

---

So, I removed this problem.